# How to solve this probability question?

Tags: probability

I just thought of this question, but I do not know how to solve it.

> If an event has a $1/1000$ chance of happening, what is the probability it happens after $1000$ trials

Comment: There are a number of ambiguous things about what you have asked.  Firstly, is each trial independent?  Next, you say "what is the probability it *happens after* 1000 trials."  What exactly do you mean by that?  Are you asking that within 1000 trials the event occurred at least once?  Are you asking that within the first 999 trials the event never happened and its first time happening was on the thousandth trial?  Are you asking something else entirely?

Comment: Depending on your answers to my questions, you will likely need to look at either the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) or the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).  If you say that the events are not known to be [independent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) then there is not enough information to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that it happens at least once in $1,000$ trials is the same as $1-P(\text{does not happen in any of the 1,000 trials})$, by the compliment rule.

The probability that it does not happen in an individual trial is $\frac{999}{1,000}$ so the probability that it does not happen in any of $1,000$ trials is $(\frac{999}{1,000})^{1,000}\approx.368$, if we assume independence. Note that this value is close to $\frac{1}{e}$. If we let $n \rightarrow \infty$ then this probability indeed approaches $\frac{1}{e}$.

Finally,

$$\begin{align*}
1-P(\text{does not happen in any of the 1,000 trials})
&= 1-(\frac{999}{1,000})^{1,000}\\\\
&\approx .6323 \\\\
\end{align*}$$